# Micropython wdt causes endless restart

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I've been testing with micropython on the NodeMCU esp8266. It all worked fine, I've been able to connect to internet, control the pins and all the stuff without problems.

But after a couple of hours, when I try to connect to micropython via serial, It is constantly restarting after 5-10 seconds, showing this message at the top.

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x40100000, len 30668, room 16
tail 12
chksum 0xe3
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load 0x3ffe8000, len 996, room 12
tail 8
chksum 0x1c
load 0x3ffe83f0, len 1064, room 0
tail 8
chksum 0xae
csum 0xae
```

It seems to be Watchdog restarting because of a crash, but actually, I erased the entire code in boot.py and main.py, and doesn't solve.
I searched on internet but I can't find a solution. The only I can do is reflashing the microchip, but after some time, it happens again.

Comment: Perform erase_flash and rewrite firmware again
https://micropython.org/download/esp32/ and also check, that you have correct firmware according to hardware you own.